# How to use Public Range value in multiple user forms?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform which will ask for a number that is then getting looked up in a spreadsheet, saving that range in a variable. When it's found the number, it will hide the first userform and bring up the second one, but in order for me to proceed with the update, I will need to use the same range that I've previously set against my variable in userform1, any idea how to do that? I have declared it as a Public variable but it still doesn't work. Code as it follows:

UserForm1:

```
Public FillRange As Range
Public BKref As Variant


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

On Error GoTo errhndlr:
    Set FillRange = Sheets("Loader").Cells.Find(TextRef.Value).Offset(0, 2)

BKref = TextRef.Value

If Not FillRange = "" Then
    UserForm1.Hide
    UserForm2.Show
    Exit Sub
ElseIf FillRange = "" Then
    MsgBox "Booking Reference cannot be empty!", vbCritical, "Error: No Booking Ref."
    UserForm1.Hide
    Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "Unexpected error, please re-start and try again. If you had this message more than 2 times, please update the line manually.", vbCritical, "Error"
    UserForm1.Hide
    Exit Sub
End If

Exit Sub

errhndlr:
MsgBox "Booking reference not found, please double-check that the booking reference you've entered is correct, alternatively update it manually.", vbCritical, "Error"
UserFrom1.Hide

End Sub
```

UserForm2:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

FillRange = TextPloaded.Value
FillRange.Offset(0, 2) = TextTime.Value
FillRange.Offset(0, 3) = TextLoader.Value

If Not TextComm.Value = "" Then
    FillRange.Offset(0, 4) = TextComm.Value
ElseIf TextComm.Value = "" Then
    FillRange.Offset(0, 4) = ""
End If

If Not FillRange = FillRange(0, -1) Then
    MsgBox "Actual and Planned pallets doesn't match, please highlight the diescrepancies on the assembly sheet!"
    BKref = FillRange.Offset(0, -2)
    Sheets("Assembly").Activate
    Sheets("Assembly").Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=BKref
    UserForm2.Hide
Else
    UserForm2.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Made a change to the original post as I've recognized some errors myself but it's still not working.

Comment: I recommend to use `Option Explicit` in **every** module/userform etc. And define your public variable in a Module not in userform1 otherwise it is public but only in userform1.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thanks for the help, I will test it and let you know if it worked so you can post it as an answer.

Comment: Like what @Pᴇʜ said, you cannot access a variable declared on one UserForm Module in another UserForm Module. All you need is to declare that variable as a `Public Varaible` on a `Standard Module` like `Module1` etc. Then you can initialize that public variable in one UserForm Module and access it's value in another UserForm Module.

Comment: Thanks, it does work now (well... that bit...), can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: @K.Robert posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make use of `Option Explicit` in every module/userform etc. This forces you to declare all variables properly and shows a message if a variable is not declared.

The issue is that if you declare `Public FillRange As Range` in Userform1 the variable is only valid in Userform1 but not in Userform2.

So I recommend to decare the variable in a Module instead of Userform1. This way it is accessible everywhere.

**Alternative**
You can access a public Userform1 variable in Userfrom2 by `Userform1.FillRange`

Answer (score -1):

Add a property in your first form:

```
Property Get FillRange() As Range
    Set FillRange = Range("A1")
End Property
```

And read it from your second form:

```
Dim FillRange
Set FillRange = UserForm1.FillRange
```